# sending email to registered users in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I'm working on a ASP.NET web site (VS2008,C#), I'm going to send email to my users, what are my options? what do I need in terms of host or server? can I use a shared host? what services should my server provide in order to be able to send email? is there any sample code for sending email?
thanks

Comment: Where is your repository of users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use google as thesmtp server (smtp.gmail.com)

```
        Int32 port = 465;
        SmtpClient client  = new SmtpClient();
        client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("yourusername", "yourpassword");
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage("fromemailaddress", "toemailaddress");
        message.Body = "Hello!";
        message.Subject = "Hello!";
        client.Send(message);
```

Also, you can put the credentials in the web.config file so you don't have to specify them wherever you send mail in your code.

Don't forget to include the following: 
    using System.Net.Mail;

Answer (score 0):

All you really need is access to an SMTP server of some kind.  This may be available from your host but they could be anywhere - all you need is an IP address and credentials.

Sending an e-mail is trivial, [take a look here](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020121616/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/072606-1.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

In order to send an email you need to provide following details :
Host Name 
Port 
If it's not SMTP server that do not need to pass NetworkCredential.

You can you Google or Hotmail host server.

For Google host server 
host name "smtp.gmail.com"
port 587 
SSL connection Yes

For Hotmail host server 
host name "smtp.live.com"
port 587/25 
SSL connection False

You can use following classes :
MailMessage
SmtpClient

Furthermore all the settings above in Asp.net can be set in webconfig

```
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="example@domain.com" deliveryMethod="Network">
          <network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587"
              userName="example@domain.com" password="password"/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

Than see sample code

```
MailMessagemessage = new MailMessage("greg@gmail.com");
message.From = new MailAddress("example@domain.com", "Greg");


SmtpClientclient = new SmtpClient();
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Send(message);
```